# Word square thriller

Tags: word, word-square

Help me find the missing words from my trashy thriller novel.

The words can be placed in order into a grid, with the same words appearing both horizontally and vertically.

For example, in this excerpt:

> I first began to suspect I was adopted in school, when my teacher told me to **** my book at **** thirty-four and read aloud to the class about how a cuckoo will lay her **** in another bird's ****.

The answer would be:

> open
> page
> eggs
> nest

Now here's a harder one:

> The meeting had gone badly. Maybe we had gone into business with the wrong people. ****** was long gone, but this country still had more than its fair share of problems. We would ****** in about twenty minutes, said my ******, a tall, well-dressed man who spoke remarkably good English. Soon, I would be at the coast. Hopefully I'd be able to relax there for a few hours, and take my mind off corporate matters. Maybe I'd even be able to do some ******.
>
> My mind far away, I didn't suspect anything wrong when we left the ****** and turned down a side street. I was shaken from my reverie when we stopped abruptly, in a deserted alley. A gun was pointed at my head.
>
> “We can find you anywhere,” he said. “Sign the contract tomorrow. Too much money is on the line for you to ruin this now. The ****** must go ahead.”

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The answer is

> `S A D D A M` 
>  `A R R I V E` 
>  `D R I V E R` 
>  `D I V I N G` 
>  `A V E N U E` 
>  `M E R G E R` 
>  
>  The meeting had gone badly. Maybe we had gone into business with the wrong people. **SADDAM** was long gone, but this country still had more than its fair share of problems. We would **ARRIVE** in about twenty minutes, said my **DRIVER**, a tall, well-dressed man who spoke remarkably good English. Soon, I would be at the coast. Hopefully I'd be able to relax there for a few hours, and take my mind off corporate matters. Maybe I'd even be able to do some **DIVING**.
>  
>  My mind far away, I didn't suspect anything wrong when we left the **AVENUE** and turned down a side street. I was shaken from my reverie when we stopped abruptly, in a deserted alley. A gun was pointed at my head.
>  
>  “We can find you anywhere,” he said. “Sign the contract tomorrow. Too much money is on the line for you to ruin this now. The **MERGER** must go ahead.”