# Word square thriller part 3

Tags: word, word-square

[Part 1, containing more instructions](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/94332/word-square-thriller)

[Part 2](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/94366/word-square-thriller-part-2?noredirect=1&lq=1)

The latest thrilling instalment! Warning: it's pretty much impossible to construct a square of this size without using some obscure words that you might have to look up.

> “Where is the formula?” the man they called Gilgamesh demanded, as I
> struggled vainly against my bonds. “I don't want to hurt you. I am not
> a cruel man.”
>
> “Tell that to the American civilians who died in the
> bio-attacks along the Eastern ________!” I shouted defiantly.
>
> “Oh, and you blame me for that? I'm almost flattered. But what would you know about it? I thought you
> were a humble ________, not some kind of spy.”
>
> I wanted to tell the truth, but if he knew for sure that I really was a businessman, maybe he'd just kill me. “And I thought you were an investor, not an Islamist terrorist!”
>
> “Me? I abandoned my faith long ago, and was cast out as an ________. It is
> money that makes the world go around. The Greeks and the Turks, they
> say their religions make them different, but they are all the same. I
> learned that as a smuggler, plying my trade through the Dardanelles
> and the Strait of ________.”
>
> “You? Working for a living?”
>
> “Do you think I got this rich by lounging around and eating stuffed ________ like a decadent towel-clad Frenchman? I worked hard for my money, and I will
> use it as I please.”
>
> “What are you seeking?”
>
> “Peace.”
>
> I laughed sardonically.
>
> “Oh no,” he clarified. “I don't mean an end to violence. I mean inner peace. ________. When I am a billionaire, then I can take care of the people I want to protect. Only then can I rest easy.”
>
> “I must say, you have an impressive vocabulary,” I said, trying
> to build some rapport.
>
> “Oh, I am a man of many talents. I can master
> whatever I set my mind to, whether it be tuning and ________ an
> outboard motor for optimum performance, tasting wine, or riding a
> horse. Would you believe I once thought to compete in a ________ event
> at the World Equestrian Games?”
>
> I tried to imagine it, but I could not.

Comment: How much time did you spend in the word square. 8-by-8 isn't trivial...

Comment: I wrote some C++ code to generate word squares, found three word lists on the internet, and merged them in the hope of creating new combinations. The program found (over a few hours) seven eight-by-eight squares, including this one, and another that was identical but with a 't' replacing the first letter of the first word. It found no nine-by-nine squares, unfortunately.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe this is the answer :

> [image]

Explanations:

> 1. Easter **Seaboard**
>  2. Humble **Exporter** fits the bill
>  3. **Apostate** - a person who forsakes his religion
>  4. **Bosporos** - The strait between Greece and Turkey
>  5. The birds **Ortolans** are eaten in the series Billion
>  6. **Ataraxia** is Greek for "undisturbed" or "untroubled"
>  7. Tuning and **retuning**
>  8. **Dressage** is one of the official equestrian events

Process:

> The strait of **Bosporus** was the simplest to find. Then, there are only a few equestrian events, and only **Dressage** matched. Then followed **Apostate** which was fairly simple with the other two in place. **Ataraxia** was found using a synonym list. **Ortolans** required an online crossword helper, since I've never heard of the word and couldn't think of anything that matched. The rest was not that hard, since almost all letters were filled in. **Exporter** was the last word I found, since it could also have been Importer.

It all seems simple in hindsight, but it took me quite some time. Overall a very nice puzzle.

Comment: One letter wrong...

Comment: Fixed the typo :) Nice puzzle!

Comment: I have a feeling there could be an alternate answer for this, is that so, @user3153372 ?

Comment: @ÉbeIsaac It wouldn't surprise me if the pre-corrected version (the 'u' was given as an 'o') is a valid alternative spelling...