# Word Square Thriller Part 4

Tags: word, word-square

[Part 1](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/94332/word-square-thriller?noredirect=1&lq=1)

[Part 2](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/94366/word-square-thriller-part-2?noredirect=1&lq=1)

[Part 3](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/94427/word-square-thriller-part-3)

The missing words, in order, make an 8 by 8 word square with the same words going down as across. (Warning: these are not words everyone will know...)

> The thugs moved ________, lurching unpredictably like those poor
>   creatures I'd seen in the seaside marketplace, trying to cut off my
>   retreat.
>
> Realising I'd never make it to the gate, I instead began to climb up
>   the scaffolding. It wasn't hard, compared to climbing the ________ of
>   the old-fashioned sailing ships I had so loved as a child.
>
> Behind the scaffolding were finely-crafted ________ supporting the
>   entablature, as though it were an ancient temple built to revere the
>   titans; the embassy must have been built in better economic times,
>   when national pride took precedence over austerity.
>
> “Be sensible,” Gilgamesh shouted up at me. “The Human ________
>   Project is too valuable for any one corporation to own. One day a
>   human might regrow an entire limb, like an axolotl! We just want our
>   share of the profits! It's for the people!”
>
> Had I been fighting for the wrong side all along? I looked down,
>   imagined myself falling. A chill ran through me, like a ________ blast
>   of wind. I couldn't trust him, not after all I'd seen.
>
> I balanced precariously on a short horizontal timber, securing two
>   upright posts together. (My eidetic memory told me it was an ________,
>   yet another example of why having a good memory is useless in a
>   crisis...)
>
> One of the thugs was climbing up after me. For want of anything to
>   drop on him, I spat on his head.
>
> “Please,” said Gilgamesh. “Act a little ________. We are both
>   civilised men, are we not?”
>
> What should I do? Give up? Destroy the formula, to prevent it falling
>   back into the wrong hands? Try to bring it back to my corporate
>   overlords? I felt like whatever I chose, future historians would judge
>   me in future history books, and the ________ of the present would try
>   me in their essays, and find me wanting...

Comment: "These are words not everyone will know". As opposed to [Ataraxia and Ortolans](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/94429/31824) ;)

Comment: I put an obscure words warning on that one too. Also, does that count as spoilers?

Comment: You might want to look up the definition of that last word. [I do not think it means what you think it means.](https://external-preview.redd.it/ZMUFunhgy_qio-zM9Auh13R4pn4bZSV7UDvB4uCiqsU.gif?format=mp4&s=a5771f56423b54657f18e32c1d963a6a89803b1d)

Answer (score 3):

This one was a lot harder to solve! The solution is:

> ```
>  C R A B W I S E
>  R A T L I N E S
>  A T L A N T E S
>  B L A S T E M A
>  W I N T E R L Y
>  I N T E R T I E
>  S E E M L I E R
>  E S S A Y E R S
> ```

What do these words mean?

> [**CRABWISE**](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/crabwise) = sideways;
>  [**RATLINES**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratlines) = part of the rigging on a ship;
>  [**ATLANTES**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atlas_(architecture)) = plural form of 'Atlas' - an architectural support sculpted in the form of a man, usually in place of a column;
>  [**BLASTEMA**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blastema) = a mass of cells capable of growth and regeneration into body parts (much like how an [axolotl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axolotl) can);
>  [**WINTERLY**](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/winterly) = occurring in winter (i.e. bitterly cold);
>  [**INTERTIE**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/intertie) = a horizontal tie between two uprights in a wooden frame;
>  [**SEEMLIER**](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/seemly) = more respectfully;
>
>  And unfortunately, I think the OP has muddled the definition of the last!
>
>  [**ESSAYERS**](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/essayer) = people who 'attempt' or 'try'...
>  whereas
>  [*ESSAYISTS*](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/essayist) = people who write essays!

These complete the story like so:

> The thugs moved **CRABWISE**, lurching unpredictably like those poor creatures I'd seen in the seaside marketplace, trying to cut off my retreat.
>
>  Realising I'd never make it to the gate, I instead began to climb up the scaffolding. It wasn't hard, compared to climbing the **RATLINES** of the old-fashioned sailing ships I had so loved as a child.
>
>  Behind the scaffolding were finely-crafted **ATLANTES** supporting the entablature, as though it were an ancient temple built to revere the titans; the embassy must have been built in better economic times, when national pride took precedence over austerity.
>
>  “Be sensible,” Gilgamesh shouted up at me. “The Human **BLASTEMA** Project is too valuable for any one corporation to own. One day a human might regrow an entire limb, like an axolotl! We just want our share of the profits! It's for the people!”
>
>  Had I been fighting for the wrong side all along? I looked down, imagined myself falling. A chill ran through me, like a **WINTERLY** blast of wind. I couldn't trust him, not after all I'd seen.
>
>  I balanced precariously on a short horizontal timber, securing two upright posts together. (My eidetic memory told me it was an **INTERTIE**, yet another example of why having a good memory is useless in a crisis...)
>
>  One of the thugs was climbing up after me. For want of anything to drop on him, I spat on his head.
>
>  “Please,” said Gilgamesh. “Act a little **SEEMLIER**. We are both civilised men, are we not?”
>
>  What should I do? Give up? Destroy the formula, to prevent it falling back into the wrong hands? Try to bring it back to my corporate overlords? I felt like whatever I chose, future historians would judge me in future history books, and the **(ESSAYERS)** of the present would try me in their essays, and find me wanting...

Solving method:

> From the off I worked on the assumption that the OP had mistakenly used '**ESSAYERS**' as the eighth word. I then reasoned that the seventh would probably end -IER from the context and considered both KINDLIER and SEEMLIER to be possibles. In fact I worked off KINDLIER for a long time, since this fitted with CRABLIKE for the first. Either way, the sixth was of the form I-----IE and this led me (after *much* Googling) to **INTERTIE**. A further Google session concerning axolotl (boy have I learned a lot about those!) eventually gave me **BLASTEMA** as the fourth, which fitted only if the seventh were **SEEMLIER**. This then meant the first could not be CRABLIKE after all - but everything else was fitting so well! That was the point at which I learned that **CRABWISE** was a real (and perfectly fitting) word...
>
>  With over half of the grid now filled, I then found **ATLANTES** (yes, Google), and **WINTERLY** (simple definition) and it was a simple search on the Internet to find the missing second letter in **RATLINES**. The puzzle was now complete!